# Trying to view alert box with button with redirecting to Index

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I tried below code and in my application I restrict the delete action for the entities with dependencies. now it works and redirecting to the index page without deleting. What I want is set an alert message for the UpdateDb exception to view users also with redirection.Please help me.

```
 // POST: Departments/5/Delete
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("{id:int:min(1)}/Delete")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                await DeleteAsync(p => p.Id == id);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException e)
            {
                RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new BadRequestObjectResult("child exists for department"));
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886084/how-to-show-success-message-in-view-when-redirecttoaction-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `TempData` and javascript.

Action:

```
catch (DbUpdateException e)
{
   TempData["Error"] = "child exists for department!";
   RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));          
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ('@TempData["Error"]' != '') {
            var jsAlert = "Error:" + '@TempData["Error"]';
            alert(jsAlert);
        }
    })


</script>
}
```

Remember to set `CookiePolicyOptions.CheckConsentNeeded` to `false` in startup.cs if you have configured it as true

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        })
```